# Can you explain the working of below relay ? It has 4 legs and it was in car

Tags: relay, automotive

[image]

It was in my car and has been replaced. Due to it car horn was not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect DC power to pins 85 and 86 that will power a small electromagnet coil.  The electromagnet then pulls the switch closed that connects pins 30 and 87.

The switch between 30 and 87 is pretty heavy duty and can handle high currents (like headlights, or other similar loads.

The current passing from pin 85 to 86 is rather low because the resistance of the bundle of wire to make the coil is thin and long. This means, only a small switch that doesn't need to handle much current can be used to activate the coil. Also, small wires can be used to run this control wire and small switch (that is, you don't need big wires running to the dashboard and big switches in the dash board).

If you cannot see the PIN numbers, use an ohm meter to look for two pins that make some low resistance (under 2000 and possibly as low as 100 ohms). Those will be your coil pins.  By default, the other two are for the large load. There should be infinite resistance between those two pins until you energize the coil.

Comment: I added a comment to my answer.

Comment: Is there an electrical connection between the relay coil and pin 30? There is a line there.

Comment: No, that should be a dashed line to show the magnetic field pulling on the switched element. A link to the datasheet is in another answer posted here.  Coil resistance should be 110ohms.

Answer (score 1):

Pins 30 and 87 are the relay contacts.  Pins 85 and 86 are the coil.

Datasheet: [Relay Datasheet](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/308896/OENINDIA/730-1A-1201-PC.html)

Comment: which pin is 30 ? I mean how to identify the pins ?

Comment: Look on the bottom of the device.  THere will be pin numbers molded into the plastic.  You may have to look hard,  move it around to different light angles.  They may be tiny (1mm??) but they're there.

Comment: That's why I posted a link to the datasheet.  Did you look at it?